# Google Directory User put api throwing 400 error (Invalid Input: [SSO])

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, google-apis-explorer, google-directory-api

I want to create single sign-on for aws using google authentication.
When I execute google directory user put api. I keep getting 400 error with message "Invalid Input: [SSO]"

```js
{
"customSchemas":
{
"SSO":
{
"role": [
        {
          "value": "arn:aws:iam::******:role/AbcAdmin,arn:aws:iam::******:saml-provider/AbcSSO",
          "customType": "AbcAdmin"
        }      
    ]
   }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to help you. Explain in greater detail and post your code that you are using.